# Webpack- hot module replacement for html pages

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-hmr

My webpage is not updated when **html** source code has changed.

It works fine with js and css (actually I use less). It doesn't work for html

Browser is asking for `***.hot-update.js` and I can see my changes in the downloaded file but html still look as before update.

DevServer config:

```
devServer: {
    contentBase: '../application/',
    useLocalIp: true,
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    watchContentBase: true,
    proxy: {
        '/': {
            target: 'http://127.0.0.1/current/WebApplication/Client/application/'
        }
    },
    hot: true,
    inline: true,
    hotOnly: true
}
```

- "webpack": "^4.20.2",
- "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2",
- "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.9"

Comment: can your webpack config file ?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to know about HtmlWebpackPlugin.

Comment: either my question is not clear at all, or you have no knowledge of webpack